# How automatically ssh to cluster servers and run command there to get some information?

Tags: ssh

A simple question, say I want to ssh to cluster machines and monitor some info of each of them. Specifically, I want to run `nvidia-smi` on each of them to know the GPU usage of them. I tried:

```
for host in machine1 machine2 machine3
 do 
    ssh "$host" 
    nvidia-smi 
 done
```

but it only logs in to `machine1`, then just stopped there. Only after I exit `machine1`, will `nvidia-smi` execute, but on the local terminal, not on `machine1`. Then it logs in to `machine2` and stops there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the command you want to execute on the `ssh` line:

```
for host in machine1 machine2 machine3
 do 
        ssh "$host" nvidia-smi 
 done
```

You might need to specify the full path of `nvidia-smi`.

Also, rather than hard-coding your list of servers into this script (and other, similar scripts), keep the list in a file:

```
cat >Servers.txt <<EOF
machine1
machine2
machine3
EOF
```

And change the `for` line to:

```
for host in $(cat Servers.txt)
```

Then, when the "list of servers" changes, you only have to change ONE place, not every script.

Comment: [Useless use of backticks.](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks) Please use a `while read` loop or, better yet, `xargs` instead.